# Module not found: Can't resolve '@stripe/react-stripe-js'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, stripe-payments

import { loadStripe } from "@stripe/stripe-js";
import { Elements } from "@stripe/react-stripe-js";
// also done with packages installation npm i @stripe/react-stripe-js and npm i @stripe/stripe-js

Error showing
./src/App.js
Module not found: Can't resolve '@stripe/react-stripe-js' in 'E:\project

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/robF1.png)

Comment: It's more likely you haven't installed `@stripe/stripe-js` package. It'd be better to show the list of installed dependencies from `package.json` here.

Comment: "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.12.3",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.2",
    "@stripe/react-stripe-js": "github:stripe/react-stripe-js",
    "@stripe/stripe-js": "^1.21.1",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.15.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "axios": "^0.24.0",
    "firebase": "^9.3.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-currency-format": "^1.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "^4.0.3",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.2"
  },

Comment: this is package.json file

Answer (score 0):

You haven't installed stripe.

make sure you have stripe in your package.json
and run "npm i" in that directory.   Then try again.